# постепенный перевод сайта на новую тему yii2

Tags: yii2

есть работающий сайт, на котором надо абгрейдить дизайн и функционал. Для этого создана тема, расположение которой в структуре файлов следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Подскажите правильный алгоритм перевода сайта на эту тему.
2. В идеале меня интересует такой вариант, при котором есть массив экшенов и контроллеров уже переписанных под эту тему, для которых включается новая тема. Для всего, что не входит в этот массив включаются старые виды. По мере работы над сайтом и готовности того или иного экшена или контроллера, в этот массив добавляется указание, что теперь для них подключаем новую тему и так дальше, пока все экшены не будут допилены. Можно ли организоваться так?
3. Метод yii\base\ViewContextInterface::getViewPath() переключает дефолтную папку вида для всех экшенов конроллера или можно переключить для конкретных экшенов?

---

Частично сделал то, что мне надо, но есть небольшой косяк. Вот код

```
    public function getViewPath()
    {
        $goodActions = ['search-provider1', 'index'];
        if (ArrayHelper::isIn($this->action->id, $goodActions)){
//            $viewPath = yii::$app->view->theme->pathMap['@app/views'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->id.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            $viewPath = '@app/themes/neat/views/' .$this->id.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        } else {
//            $viewPath = 'home/oughtem/27082017.net/www/frontend/views/' .$this->id.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            $viewPath = '@app/views/' .$this->id.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        }

        return $viewPath;
    }

    public function actionSearchProvider(){
        $get = yii::$app->request->get();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->getViewPath());
        //@app/themes/neat/views/site/
        //@app/views/site/
        return $this->render($this->action->id,[
            'get' => $this->getViewPath(),
        ]);
//        return $this->render($this->getViewPath().$this->action->id,[
//            'get' => $this->getViewPath(),
//        ]);
    }
```

Оба метода добавлены в основном контроллере. Из метода `getViewPath()` я могу получить нужный мне путь в зависимости от того готов у меня эшен или нет, но независимо от того какой из путей

```
//@app/themes/neat/views/site/
//@app/views/site/
```

я передаю в метод render рендерится всё равно вид из `themes/neat/views/site/`. Исключением является только тот случай, когда в папке `themes/neat/views/site/` отсутствует файл вида. Тогда получив тот же самый ответ от `getViewPath()` рендерится файл из `views/site/`.

Из документации метода рендер

> ```
>  * The view to be rendered can be specified in one of the following formats:
>  *
>  * - [path alias](guide:concept-aliases) (e.g. "@app/views/site/index");
>  * - absolute path within application (e.g. "//site/index"): the view name starts with double slashes.
>  *   The actual view file will be looked for under the [[Application::viewPath|view path]] of the application.
>  * - absolute path within module (e.g. "/site/index"): the view name starts with a single slash.
>  *   The actual view file will be looked for under the [[Module::viewPath|view path]] of [[module]].
>  * - relative path (e.g. "index"): the actual view file will be looked for under [[viewPath]].
> ```

становиться ясно, что если передать path alias, то замены не должно быть, но она всё равно происходит.

Собственно вопрос несколько видоизменился: как заставить render рендерить нужный мне вид, а не переопределять его?

Comment: Разве не проще перекинуть старые файлы видов в новую тему? И переключить сайт целиком и полностью на новую тему. А потом постепенно переделать старые виды под новую тему.

Comment: не проще. Дело в том, что css старых видов не коннектится с css новых видов. В каждом виде надо поправлять. Если залить всё, как вы предлагаете, потом сложно будет разобраться где поменял, а где нет. Мне надо сделать именно так, как я написал: если этот вид указан в условии, то он юзается из темы, если нет, то юзается со старых видов. плиз хел, очень надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За основу логики взял ответ товарища **fedornabilkin**, но техническое исполнение оставил за собой, т.к. решение

> Соответственно трейт подключаем в нужные контроллеры

не вызывало оптимизма. Контроллеров много и искать нужные и не нужные не особо хотелось. Сделал helper

```
    public function hasView($controller_id, $action_id){
    $good_view = [
        'site' => ['index', 'static-page'],
        'provider' => ['settings'],
        'categories' => ['search-view'],
    ];

    if (in_array($action_id, $good_view[$controller_id])) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

а в main.php добавил

```
    'view' => [           
        'theme' => [               
            'class'=> yii\base\Theme::className(),               
            'basePath'=> '@app/themes/neat/web',    // путь в дир-ию темы, базовая директория, в которой размещены темизированные ресурсы (CSS, JS, изображения, и так далее).             
            'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/neat/web',   // базовый URL для доступа к темизированным ресурсам.            
            'pathMap' => [                   
                '@app/views'    => '@app/themes/neat/views',     
                '@app/web/img'  => '@app/web/neat/img',               
            ],           
        ],      
    ],
```

+ там же ниже

```
    'on beforeAction' => function ($event) {
    if ((\frontend\helpers\NewViewHelper::hasView(Yii::$app->controller->id, Yii::$app->controller->action->id))){
        Yii::$app->view->theme = null;
    }
```

Т.е. по дефолту переопределил всё, если нужный экшен не указан в массиве готовых экшенов сбиваю ему свойство theme в null.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы в таком случае сделал таким образом. Учитывая, что этот костыль временный.

В параметрах `project/frontend/config/params.php` создаем массив, в котором укажем список контроллеров и экшенов, которые переведены на новую тему.

```
'upgradeView' => [
    'controllerId' => ['actionId'],
]
```

Далее создаем трейт, в котором получим массив контроллеров из параметров и проверим наличие текущего экшена. Если если экшн для текущего контроллера переведен на новую тему, то переключим компонент `view` на новую тему. Выглядит приблизительно так.

```
Yii::$app->getView()->theme = '@app/themes/neat';
```

Соответственно трейт подключаем в нужные контроллеры. Переключалку темы делаем в `beforeAction()`.